# Which characters to take into account when calculating unicity distance?

Tags: block-cipher, unicity-distance

I need to calculate the unicity distance of a block cipher. Assuming I know that the plaintext is an English message I considered using 53 as the size of the alphabet, since the message could contain lowercase ans uppercase letters from the english alphabet, as well as whitespace.
Would this be the right way to approach this calculation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get much lower if you use dictionaries containing English words.

Comment: Unfortunately the use of such dictionaries is not an option for now.

Comment: @GeorgeG: are you saying that you forbid the attacker from using a dictionary of English words?  That's the point CodesInChaos is making. A plaintext of "cKwpTzuQ" is not English, while "I believe" is; a model that accepts both doesn't account for the redundancy within English text.

Comment: @poncho yes, that is what I meant. The scenario described above is based on an assignment.  However, my question is not restricted to this assignment only, it has a more general nature. I could rephrase it as "If we encrypt an english message that might contain lowercase and uppercase letters, as well as whitespaces, what would be the alphabet size to be used when calculating the unicity distance for the ciphertext?". I'm only asking this because I remember reading somewhere that taking only lowercase letters into account (size=26) would do the trick but it sounds wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alphabet size you need to consider, when calculating the [unicity distance](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance), is the size of the *ciphertext* alphabet.  This follows from the definition of unicity distance, as the amount of *ciphertext* needed to rule out all but one of the keys.*

- For a classical cipher that only encrypts letters to letters, and ignores spaces and case distinctions, the alphabet size would be 26 (or possibly less, e.g. if I and J are merged together).
- For a cipher that uses exactly the alphabet you described (upper- and lowercase letters and spaces) for both plaintext and ciphertext, the alphabet size would be 2 × 26 + 1 = 53.
- For a modern cipher that outputs one 8-bit byte for each plaintext character, the alphabet size would be 256.
- For a hypothetical cipher that only outputs *7-bit* bytes, the alphabet size would be 128.

Note that, in the formula $U = H_k / D$ for the unicity distance, the per-character redundancy $D$ should really be interpreted as *the number of bits of information revealed by one additional ciphertext character.*

This can be calculated as the number of bits encoded by one ciphertext character (i.e. as log<sub>2</sub>(alphabet size), if we assume the ciphertext to have no redundancy), minus the number of bits of entropy per plaintext character, *assuming that each ciphertext character decrypts to one plaintext character.*  For ciphers where this is not always the case, like the [VIC cipher](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIC_cipher) or other fractionating ciphers, things get more complicated.

(Another example of a fractionating cipher would be a modern block cipher in a [mode](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) like ECB or CBC that always encrypts or decrypts one full block at a time.  For such ciphers, it's arguably more meaningful to calculate the unicity distance in units of blocks rather than characters.  Of course, you can then convert the result back to, say, bytes, and typically get the same result as if you'd assumed a one-byte block size to begin with.  But you still can't really decrypt a partial block with such a cipher — except by brute force iterating over the missing part of the block, which makes your already slow brute force attack even slower.)

It's also worth noting that the whole concept of a constant "plaintext entropy per character" is somewhat nonsensical, since it's not really fixed — typically, the more plaintext you already have, the easier the next character is to predict (and, thus, the less entropy it carries).  The plaintext entropy also depends strongly on the assumed distribution of plaintexts, and, in practice, on how good the attacker is at recognizing valid plaintexts.  Thus, reasonable estimates for the unicity distance of the same cipher can in fact vary widely, depending what assumptions one makes.

---

<sup>***)** In fact, this "casual" definition I gave has a subtle error: for most ciphers, there is *no* amount of ciphertext that can be *guaranteed* to rule out all keys but the correct one.  Rather, the usual formula for calculating the unicity distance gives approximately the amount of ciphertext needed to reduce the *expected number of false positives* (i.e. wrong keys that randomly yield a plausible decryption) to one.</sup>

<sup>This means that, if you have exactly one unicity distance worth of ciphertext, and try to decrypt it with all keys by brute force, you will, on average, end up with *two* keys that give a plausible plaintext — one correct key, and, on average, one false positive.  To actually be reasonably sure of getting no false positives at all, you'll need *more* than one unicity distance of ciphertext.</sup>

Comment: @GeorgeG: in addition to Ilmari's correct comments, there's another issue with unicity distance -- it's not very useful.  Not only does it vary depending on the plaintext and the capability of the attacker (as Ilmari points to), in practice (and with real plaintext distributions) it's tiny -- somewhat larger than the key size.  When we use AES to encrypt something, we're generally interested in encrypting more than 24 or 32 characters.  Hence, we cannot depend on unicity distance; instead, we must rely on the computation complexity of breaking AES.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming, you only have 7 bit ASCII characters (since you are using a block cipher, I assume the use of a computer), you have to consider:

- Each character takes 7 bit
- English language has about 1,5 (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance)) bit entropy per character
- Considering both upper and Lower Letter cases is not necessary, because in almost any case, the language allows just one of them. Considering the character case does not increase the languages entropy per symbol.

$\Rightarrow$ Redundancy is about 5.5 bit per character.

Then you need the keysize of your block cipher, and use the formula

$$U = H(k) / D$$
With distance $U$ (in characters), Entropy  $H(k)$ of the key (in bit), and redundancy $D$  (in bit per character). (formula taken from the wikipedia article).

With 128 bits in the key, this is only $\approx 23.27$  characters.

Comment: This is wrong: Unicity distance is the amount of ciphertext you need before there is likely to be one key that decrypts it into a plausible plaintext.  Are you really saying that, with 4 bytes of ciphertext, there is likely to be only one 128 bit key that decrypts it into a plausible English plaintext?  I believe you'd find the answer (using your Entropy model, which isn't really that accurate for short texts) to be closer to 20 characters.

Comment: The math is correct, as far as it goes, but the unicity distance is measured in characters, not in bits (at least if $D$ is measured in bits / character; if you measured $D$ in, say, bits / cipher block, then $U$ would be in cipher blocks). So the correct answer should be $U\approx 23.27$ *characters* (except that this assumes 7-bit bytes, even though pretty much every digital cipher ever works on 8-bit bytes, so $D$ *should* be around $6.5$, not $5.5$, giving $U\approx19.69$ characters -- pretty close to @poncho's 20 characters).

Comment: Corrected the *character* and *bit* error there. Anyway, 23 characters is still not that much (just a little over 1 block, if you consider a block size of 128). About the 7 bit assumption: I assumed ASCII. And that is 7 bit per character. If you dump your ascii into 8 bit data types, then you are correct with 19.69 characters.