# Unicity Distance - AES

Tags: aes, unicity-distance

I am quite confused calculating the unicity distance and I was hoping that someone can clarify some things for me.

My main issue comes from somewhat a difference of the calculation given by our teacher and the one I find in wikipedia/other topics in here 
as stated in [this question / answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22927/which-characters-to-take-into-account-when-calculating-unicity-distance).
$U=\frac{H(k)}{D}$
With distance $U$ (in characters), Entropy $H(k)$ of the key (in bit), and redundancy $D$ (in bit per character) (formula taken from [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicity_distance#Relation_with_key_entropy_and_plaintext_redundancy)).

Now what I have given is
$UD = \frac{log_2(|K|) * log_2(|P|)}{Rl}$ ,
where $|K|$ is the number of keys, $|P|$ is the number of plaintext characters
and $Rl$ is the redundancy of the plaintext language.

Now I am having troubles calculating for example the $UD$ of AES 128 bits.

So I guess $|K| = 2^{128}, |P| = 26$, thus it gives  $38.9$

I tried computing different options but I never really got the answer from the article linked above where it is 20 characters.
What am I doing wrong?